# How to update session.setAttribute(name,value) value, where the name is same?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a situation where I need to update the value of a setAttribute where the name remains same. Consider the following situation as example-
Suppose I have three JSP: abc.jsp, xyz.jsp, pqr.jsp. Now at first abc.jsp runs then control forward to xyz.jsp & then forward to pqr.jsp. Now after execute pqr.jspthe control back to xyz.jsp again with a updated value at setAttribute.
**abc.jsp:**

```
ArrayList<Books> getSupplyStatus=new ArrayList<Books>();
JavaBean javaBean=new JavaBean();
session=request.getSession(false);
getSupplyStatus=javaBean.getSupplyStatus(memberID); //It returns a ArrayList 
if(!getSupplyStatus.isEmpty())
{
  session.setAttribute("UpdatedBooklist", getSupplyStatus);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("xyz.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

**xyz.jsp:**

```
session=request.getSession(false);
ArrayList<Books> getSupplyStatus=(ArrayList<Books>) session.getAttribute("UpdatedBooklist");
// some operations & forward to pqr.jsp
```

**pqr.jsp:**

```
// in this jsp new ArrayList<Books> will be prodeuced
// & I need to bound the value of "UpdatedBooklist" with 
// which is set in abc.jsp,
// and previous value must be override & then forward to xyz.jsp again
// In xyz.jsp we recieve the updated value.
```

Comment: Please clarify your question more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using setAttribute() again will [replace the value](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and call the necessary lifecycle methods.

> If an object was already bound to this session of this name that implements HttpSessionBindingListener, its HttpSessionBindingListener.valueUnbound method is called.

You can also use [removeAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#removeAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) and set an attribute with the same name again. If by 'update' you mean you want the object updated and not replaced, then get the attribute with `getAttribute()` and call methods on it that will mutate the object.