# Cant save data using session

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I have this web app that should count the sum of those card coded in every input. It's successful but data wont persist. Here is my code.

Controller:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String BusName = "";
    String PlateNumber = "";
    String DriverAssigned = "";

    try{            
        BusName = request.getParameter("busName");
        PlateNumber = request.getParameter("plateNo");
        DriverAssigned = request.getParameter("driverAssigned");

        String firstString = PlateNumber.substring(0, 2);
        String secondString = PlateNumber.substring(3, 5);

        if (firstString.matches(".*[A-Z].*") && secondString.matches(".*\\d.*")){

        CalculatorBean beanCalc = BeanFactory.getInstance(BusName, PlateNumber, DriverAssigned);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("deJesusBean", beanCalc);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("displayresult.jsp");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

My model for the logic:

```
public void compute(){
    char x = plateNo.charAt(5);

        if (x == '1' || x == '2'){
            dayOfCoding = "Monday";
            mondayCoding = mondayCoding + 1;
        }
        else if (x == '3' || x == '4'){
            dayOfCoding = "Tuesday";
            tuesdayCoding = tuesdayCoding + 1;
        }
        else if (x == '5' || x == '6'){
            dayOfCoding = "Wednesday";
            wednesdayCoding = wednesdayCoding + 1;
        }
        else if (x == '7' || x == '8'){
            dayOfCoding = "Thursday";
            thursdayCoding = thursdayCoding + 1;
        }
        else if (x == '9' || x == '0'){
            dayOfCoding = "Friday";
            fridayCoding = fridayCoding + 1;
        }
    }
```

and I display it using 
`${deJesusBean.mondayCoding}`

Comment: what do you mean by "It's successful but data wont persist."?

Comment: it needs to save the values so if setAttribute will overwite? what can I use?

Answer (score -1):

you need to delete or invalidate the session try the following code

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if(session.getAttribute("deJesusBean") != null){
   session.removeAttribute("deJesusBean");
   session.setAttribute("deJesusBean", beanCalc);
}
```

Comment: if you will invalidate the session how user will be able to proceed, it will be logged out.. :)

Comment: in this case just delete and create

Comment: how can you delete a session? the code you wrote above that means you are removing some attribute from session and setting it again, even if there is an attribute in session object and you are setting new value with `session.setAttribute("deJesusBean", beanCalc);` then previous value will be overridden.

Comment: `setAttribute` will overwrite the existing bean anyway, so this code will not have any extra effect.

Comment: so if setAttribute will overwite? what can I use?

Comment: same question as this, just use remove and set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917792/how-to-update-session-setattributename-value-value-where-the-name-is-same

Comment: I tried but still data cant be saved. and out the sum